# getJSON working in all browsers except local Firefox

Tags: jquery, json, firefox

I have the following code that is calling the alert for all browsers (Opera, Chrome, IE) except my Local Firefox.

```
 $.getJSON('Banner.php?getBanners=1', function(data) {
            alert(data);
    });
```

The strange thing is that this code is also working on Firefox on other computers.

Is this a bug in firefox? Do I need to install/reinstall?

If this is off-topic, is there somewhere I can re-ask this or that this can be migrated to?

Comment: Does the http request succeed? Are you potentially running a Firefox extension (like AdBlock) that interferes?

Comment: The HTTP request never enters the line with `alert()`. I am running `adblock` and never considered this could be the problem. I will disable it and give it a try.

Comment: @zdyn Very nice answer/comment. After disabling adblock my request is running successfully. Feel free to answer and add additional information for me to accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One Firefox extension really helpful in this case is Firebug: http://getfirebug.com/. If you open Firebug and look in the Net tab, you can view the status of all HTTP requests on your page.

The reason I suspected AdBlock is 2-fold. One, you mentioned the problem manifests only on Firefox and AdBlock is probably the most popular extension. Two, AdBlock blocks certain HTTP requests by filtering based on URLs, and I imagine something like Banner in the URL (i.e. banner ads) would get caught by the filter.

Comment: Yeh..I have firebug but usually use the script debugger. Next time I will also check the Net tab. Thanks!